# SPSS - export image - stop it appending '1' to filename

Tags: export, spss

If I export an image, i.e. a graph, from SPSS output viewer, it always appends '1' to the file name.

I specify the filename as `somegraph.png` and it gets exported as `somegraph1.png`, even when there is no such file existing in the directory.

I do this using the dialogue, i.e. right-click on the graph and export.

Does anyone know how to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

When you are exporting graphics, you get one file per chart, hence the numeric suffix, which starts with the second chart.  But if you export only a single chart, there is no numeric suffix added.